# Can I use a dash to replace a repeating verb?

Tags: verbs, dashes, em-dashes

In my language (Bulgarian) you can use a dash to replace a verb that you have already used in the same sentence. For example:

> The distance from London to Paris is 500km, from Paris to Munich —
> 850km, and from Munich to Luxembourg — 530km.

Is this is any way grammatically correct in English, or is there a way to recreate it using different punctuation? I simply want to omit the "to be" verb the second and third time I'm using it in a row in the exact same context.

Comment: We would use a comma and not a dash.

Comment: Many (possibly most) people would use zero punctuation in place of the dash to avoid comma clutter.

Comment: The dash does not really replace anything - it creates a short pause. The context and cadence allows the listener/reader to insert the obvious words. If you wish to put words in its place, they would be "It/The distance is"

Comment: I second @Edwin Ashworth; you'd better use zero punctuation here— as is par for the course in ellipsis, which it's an example of.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate it. So simply writing "The distance from London to Paris is 500km and from Paris to Munich 850km." is correct?